# Is it correct to say "he called her near"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say "he called her near"? Meaning, "he called her, asking her to come near". I did find some results on google, but not enough to remove any doubt. Typing "called her near" I got 47500 hits, but then browsing through the pages they shrank to only 46!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. There is an example in some translations of the Bible:

> "Having seen her, Jesus called her near and said to her '...' " (Luke13:12)

But it is rather old-fashioned and there are other ways to express this. You could say:

> He called her over
>   He called her to him
>   He called her to his side

Or use your paraphrase

> He asked her to come near to him